# Mathematical Induction with Fermat's last theorem?

Tags: number-theory

Question on Fermat's Last theorem:

> $\nexists a,b,c\in \mathbb N:a^n+b^n = c^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N, n\ge 2$.

Assume that we have shown a proof for the cases $n = 3$ and $n = 4$.
Can we say that via mathematical induction that this is now true for all $n \in \mathbb N$?

Comment: Would it have taken 350 years to prove this if we could have solved this by a simple enough induction to explain on this website?

Comment: This is what is jokingly called _proof by example_. It's not a proof at all for that matter.

Comment: Oh so it can't be done this way? I'm still new to learning math so. I mean I thought it was dumb to ask I guess.

Comment: There *is* an inductive proof as follows. Suppose $a^n+b^n\ne c^n$ for all $2<n<N$, $a, b, c\in\mathbb{N}$. Then by the published proof of Fermat's Last Theorem, $a^N+b^N\ne c^N$ for all $a, b, c\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret That's not really inductive since we don't _use_ the hypothesis.

Comment: How do you get to the next step?  That is, how could you settle the case $n=5$ once the smaller cases are settled?  That is the characteristic of a proof by induction.

Comment: @AlexR Clearly the induction hypothesis in conjunction with the general proof implies the $N$ case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course not. I remind you of induction : if $P(n)$ is a proposition depending on $n$, we have $$P(0)\land (\forall n, P(n))\Rightarrow P(n+1))\Rightarrow (\forall n, P(n))$$ which in common tongue means that if $P$ is valid for $0$ and that for an arbitrary $n$ $P(n)$ implies $P(n+1)$ than $P(n)$ is proven by induction. On the case you describe you have not proven implication for arbitrary $n$

Comment: So the proof must actually be given first. I must show that there is an implication on n first. Then, show it true for an arbitrary value. And this then we can do the proof from n+1? Am I getting it or?

Comment: The sequence is to prove for an initial value and then prove for $n+1$ assuming $n$ is true